# How to diagnose 'Resolving timeout'?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, dns

I have a php app that is on AWS EC2, and is making a call to AWS ALB endpoint using php curl. I see this intermittent error, once every 6 requests. I am not able to reproduce. What would be a way to diagnose this problem? Appreciate any help.

```
cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 60 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Comment: full code required.

Comment: Without more information, there's no way to know if it's on the AWS side or the client side. Check your logs on AWS and see what pops up.

Comment: Does your ALB connect to an RDS instance? If so then can you check the CPU history on that RDS

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, and you aren't providing enough information to answer, so this isn't one. The message indicates that the problem is coming from the [curl](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library, which is used to make network calls. It indicates a timeout, and the value of 60 milliseconds seems really low (generally you time out after some number of seconds) so I'd look for configuration that sets the timeout. And finally, it indicates that the timeout happens during DNS resolution, so I'd look for a misconfigured DNS server.